does pg_restore + wal_type=replica create a consistent replica?
I have a PostgreSQL server that has a pg_dump scheduled every day at 3 AM (low traffic time window) for backup purposes. These dump files are gzipped and stored at a convenient location. This server also has wal_type=replica and proper user with replication roles already set up, and already a hot stand by replica being synchronized.
I need to create a second replica from this server, and I'd like to know if I can leverage my 3 AM pg_dump backups to avoid executing another pg_dump on the primary. Let's say I do the following:

at 10 AM I grab the 3 AM dump file from the primary server
pg_restore it into a new server (replica #2)
set recovery.conf -> primary_conninfo in this new server pointing to the primary
replica #2 start

My question is, will the replication process pick up at 3 AM (date of the dump file) and replicate all the way to the present time? Or do I have to take any additional precautions?
As a related question: If the above works, does this mean I could potentially grab any dump file from any date, and the wal replication will take care of the elapsed time and bring it up to date?

No. Physical replication (wal_type=replica) can not being setted up using a dump from pg_dump. You need to use pg_basebackup for that instead.

Thanks @RabbanKeyak. Would you elaborate on why pg_dump cannot be used in this scenario? What are the limitations/risks? Could it be used if I manually do whatever pg_dump does not? (for example, manually copying database configuration?).

For streaming replication, the standby server needs to be initialized with a physical copy of the actual database files, as created for example by pg_basebackup. You cannot use a logical backup created by pg_dump to initialize a streaming replication standby server.

Thanks for your reply. I'm confused about the limitations of using pg_dump instead of pg_basebackup. For example AWS says that pg_dump is an acceptable way of doint an intial "full load" prior to setting up an "ongoing replication" for migrating on premises DBs to their cloud. Why are they not recomending pg_basebackup instead? I'm guessing because their managed RDS solution does not allow to restore a full backup. But if so, why is pg_dump safe to use anyways? (link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-manageddatabases.postgresql-rds-postgresql.html)

They are probably talking about logical replication, not streaming replication.
